# Is time a measurement of loss of energy?

Tags: time

I know it sounds dumb . I'm not entirely sure whether this question is indeed suitable to ask here or the philosophy stack exchange . Anyways just hear me out alright ? People age . objects age . But particles don't . Again isotopes age . So I'm guessing time is related to energy . We (I mean our cells slowly lose their working efficiency) . That's why maybe our cells get old . Again isotopes radiate energy . That's maybe why we count their half life . But maybe particles don't radiate energy . That's why maybe particles don't change . So maybe they don't age . If all these assumptions are correct ,then maybe in twin paradox ,the brother who travels at the speed of light ,for him loss of energy occurs slowly than the other brother . Maybe that's why time flows differently for them . Again our universe maybe don't age cause no energy is lost from it . So now how scientific does this shit sound?

Answer (score 3):

**Not scientific at all**

E.g. the Earth is a net recipient of energy (which it is getting from the Sun). Your theory would imply the Earth is somehow getting younger as a result, which it obvious isn't.